# What should I do to resolve salesforce security review?

Tags: apex, security-review

I had run a security review for my apex code. It returned a number of FLS update error in the result. I have changed/implemented code (see below the code snippet) but the error is still there. Please give me your suggestion if I am following a wrong path.

This is the screenshot of the security review

[image: screenshot of the security review]

and the code I have implemented is like this

```
 if (Schema.sObjectType.Object__c.fields.Id.isAccessible() && sysPol != null)
        obj.id = sysPol;

    if(Object__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable())
        update obj;
```

Comment: check this repos update method https://github.com/sonicfurqan/CheckCURDSalesforce/blob/master/CrudPermision

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to consider all outcomes (if/else) in your code:

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.Object__c.fields.Id.isAccessible() == false){
 //do nothing
}else{
  if(sysPol != null) obj.id = sysPol;
}

if(Object__c.sObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable() ==false){
//do nothing
}else{
  update obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its also important check `isUpdatable()` access for fields participating in update operation.

Here are some documents for reference:

1. [Requirements Checklist](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Requirements_Checklist)
2. [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS), example from documentation:

   ```
   public PageReference updateStatus() {
       // Check if the user has update access on the Contact.Status__c field
       if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Status__c.isUpdateable()){
         // throw custom exception
       }
       c.Status__c = statusToSet;
       update c;
       return null;
     }
   }
   ```

---

Would recommend using the Financial force open source library [`fflib-apex-common`](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/fflib/src/classes/fflib_SecurityUtils.cls)
 by Andrew Facet!